# Formal languages: intersection of l1 and l2?

Tags: formal-languages

Please help me with the next problem: given the language

$L_1=\{a^n b^m | n\geq1, m\geq 0\}$ and $L_2=\{a^n b^2 a^ {2m} | n,m\geq0\}$ 
construct the finite automaton of the intersection of $L_1$ and $L_2$. I don't know what I am supposed to do.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I am sorry but i don t know how to use it for my problem.

Comment: You must have some idea about the strings that lie in both $L_1$ and $L_2$!

Comment: This is almost the same question as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2629945/intersection-of-two-languages-formal-languages-and-automata-theory?rq=1) and the answer is the same.